# Robotium not running all tests

Tags: java, android, testing, robotium

I have a Robotium test suite that I am trying to run and for some reason it only runs the first test, then freezes after that. I have let the program run for a few minutes, but it just sits there saying "test running". Here is my code:

```
import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class ODPRobotiumTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {

    private static final String TARGET_PACKAGE_ID = "com.gravitymobile.app.hornbill";
    private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME = "com.vzw.odp.LaunchActivity";

    private static Class<?>launcherActivityClass;

    static{
        try{
            launcherActivityClass = Class.forName(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "deprecation" })
    public ODPRobotiumTest() throws ClassNotFoundException{
        super(TARGET_PACKAGE_ID, launcherActivityClass);
    }

    private Solo solo;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception{
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    public void testLine1(){


        solo.searchText("Easy to Find");        

    }
    public void testLine2(){



        solo.searchText("Hassle-Free");


    }
    public void testLine3(){




        solo.searchText("Trust");


    }
    public void testLine4(){

        solo.searchText("Verizon Curated Wallpaper");


    }
    public void testLine5(){

        solo.searchText("Taco's");

    }
    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception{
        try{
            solo.finalize();
        }catch(Throwable e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        getActivity().finish();
        super.tearDown();
    }
}
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Here is the Junit:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer: You have to include `solo.finishOpenedActivities();` in the tearDown() method. This will "finish" the test and then begin the new test! Whew!

Thank you to everyone who offered help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any assertions in your tests (although I wouldn't think this would be the problem) What doe the Junit panel show when they're running?

or try:

```
 public void testLine1(){
    assertTrue(solo.searchText("Easy to Find"));        
 }
```

Comment: When I use the assertTrue, the tests fail, as you can see from the picture I added. In that test I used the assertTrue for the first line, like you suggested, and it failed. But what I was looking for is in the program. It is giving me a false negative

Comment: @BlaineAnderson well that's good, at least it pointed out that the first test was running and hanging

Answer (score 1):

You need to annotate the tests to run as part of the suite. Try:

```
@Smoke
public void testLine1(){
    solo.searchText("Easy to Find");  
}
```

Keep in mind that you aren't asserting anything in these tests, so they aren't very useful yet. You'll need to add assertions to check that your code is functioning properly

Comment: This is Junit3 you don't need to annotate the tests to be part of the suite, you just have to start the method name with `public void test`